# Javascript dragenter Insert Into List

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a drag-and-drop list, when I drag I want the dropzone to be inserted above the previous element. The dropzone needs to be inserted above the previous element.

The problem I have is when an item is dragged, it will constantly insert and then delete it. How can I insert a dropzone without that flicker?

EDIT: It seems I only get this problem in Firefox.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('#list ul li');
let counter;

function startDrag(event) {
    event.target.classList.add("dragStartClass");
    event.dataTransfer.setData('dragPoint', event.target.attributes['data-value'].nodeValue);
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
}

function dragEnter(event) {
    counter = 0;
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.target.localName == 'li' && event.target.attributes['data-value'] != null) {
        let dropPosition = event.target.attributes['data-value'].nodeValue;
        let draggedItem = event.dataTransfer.getData('dragPoint'); 
        let dropTarget = document.querySelectorAll("[data-value='" + dropPosition + "']")[0];
        
        let dropNode = document.createElement('li');
        dropNode.className = 'dropzone';

        dropTarget.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', dropNode);
        counter++;
        
    }
}

function dragLeave(event) {
    if (counter === 0) {
        let dropzone = document.querySelectorAll(".dropzone")[0];
        if (dropzone !== undefined) {
            dropzone.remove();
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('dragstart', startDrag);
document.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
document.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave, false);
```

```css
#list ul li {
    width: 150px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
#list ul li.dropzone {
    width: 44px;
    height: 25px;
    background: none;
    border: 3px dashed #222;
    opacity: 35%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
            <ul>
                <li draggable="true" data-value="1">1</li>
                <li draggable="true" data-value="2">2</li>
                <li draggable="true" data-value="3">3</li>
                <li draggable="true" data-value="4">4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What's the point of this drag and drop list if it never changes?

Comment: @zer00ne I haven't got that far yet, I'm trying to implement dropzones first.